# Flask Login sessions not persisting when page changes

Tags: python, session, flask, flask-login, flask-socketio

I am using flask-login, flask and socketio in python. When I log in the user as can be seen in the login_data() function the session variables are set correctly by flask-login. However when the route changes all of the session variables are lost, which causes flask login to disallow the user to access the /overview page. I have tried long and hard and cannot think why the session variables are lost, I have tried it in chrome, firefox and internet explorer, all with the same outcome.

p.s - I know I am not hashing passwords, I will get around to that after this.

main.py:

```
#Store
from flask import *
import nltk
import functools
import re
from users import User
#from flask_socketio import SocketIO,send,emit,disconnect
from flask_socketio import *
from flask_login import LoginManager,login_user,current_user,login_required
import flask_login
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.database

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key= 'lemon'
socketio = SocketIO(app)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(email):
    print('email given: '+email)
    cursor = db.users.find_one({"user.email":str(email)})
    if not cursor:
        return None
    return User(email)



@app.route('/')
def home():
    print('overview session')
    for i in session:
        print(session[i])
    return render_template('index.html')



@app.route('/login')
def login():

    return render_template('login.html')


@app.route('/overview')
@login_required
def overview():
    return render_template('overview.html')

@socketio.on('login_data')
def login_data(email,password):
    cursor = db.users.find_one({"user.email":str(email),"user.password":str(password)})
    if cursor:
        user = User(cursor['user']['email'])
        print(user.get_id())
        login_user(user,remember=True)
        print('sessions')
        for i in session:
            print(session[i])

        emit('auth',[True,current_user.email])
    else:
        emit('auth',False)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app,host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

Users Class:

```
#Users.py
from pymongo import MongoClient
class User(object):
    def __init__(self,email):
        self.email = email

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True
    def is_active(self):
        return True
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False
    def get_id(self):
        return unicode(self.email)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to this myself. For some unknown reason you cannot use the login_user function of flask-login inside of a flask-socketio event handler, it must instead be done through a normal post request.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Flask-Login's login_user function modifies the user session, and there are certain restrictions imposed by Flask-SocketIO with regards to making changes to the user session. See https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#access-to-flask-s-context-globals.